# Please check my solution

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$x=5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}$

$x^{\frac{1}{5}}=5^{5^{5^5}}$

$x=5^{x^{\frac{1}{5}}}$

$x^5 = 5^x$

$x=5$

which is obviously false

Comment: Well, $5^{5^{5^{5^{5}}}\cdot \frac15} \neq 5^{5^{5^{5}}}$.

Comment: $\left(5^{5^{5^{5^5}}}\right)^{1/5}=5^{5^{-1}\cdot 5^{5^{5^5}}}=5^{5^{-1+5^{5^5}}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second line, to remove one $5$, take $\log_5$:

$$\log_5 x = 5^{5^{5^5}}$$

---

The general misconception here is that

$$a^{b^c} = a^{(b^c)} \ne (a^b)^c$$

So both the second and fourth lines were done wrongly.

Comment: Yes, this is was such a silly mistake! I thought $a^{(b^c)}= (a^b)^c$.

Answer (score 1):

From the first step take the $\frac{1}{5}$th power on both sides:
$$x=5^{5^{5^{5^{5}}}}\longrightarrow x^\frac{1}{5}=\left(5^{5^{5^{5^{5}}}}\right)^\frac{1}{5}=5^{(5^{5^{5^{5}}})\times \frac{1}{5}}\ne 5^{5^{5^{5}}}$$